# Git post-recieve hook not running after git push

Tags: git, jenkins

I need to call the [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) build process after each push.

I followed documentation in http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

but it does not run when I push to my master branch.  When I execute manually the script "post-receive", it works fine.

My hook looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
curl http://localhost:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=git@localhost:/opt/git/project.com.git
```

For permissions, the script has 0777 permissions.

I added the hook in server inside and client inside but it still not working...

GIT Version: 1.8.3.2 running under Ubuntu 13.10

Do you how to fix this ?

Comment: Could you run `cd $(git rev-parse --git-dir) && ls -l hooks/post-receive` from within the repo to triple check everything is like you say?

Comment: 777 is a bad idea for permissions. You almost never need world write permission for a script, it will create a warm and fuzzy security hole allowing anyone to run code for you. Use 755 instead.

Comment: @Sir Athos:I know it's a bad idea, but i give it that permissions to be sure that it was not a problem of permissions

Comment: @mgarciaisaia: here is the result of your suggested command:

-rwxr-xr-x 1 skander skander 279 févr. 18 20:50 hooks/post-recieve

Comment: It's misspelled. You want `post-receive`. I've never done that myself. You believe me, don't you?